# DeleteTopic on AzureServiceBus using Powershell given ConnectionString

Tags: powershell, azure, azureservicebus

I have a service bus Connectionstring like

```
Endpoint=sb://my-bus.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=<secret key>
```

I can use that in my .Net code to manage the service bus, like create/delete topics and subscriptions.

How can I achieve the same using Powershell?

Thanks

Comment: Here is the [MSDN page for PowerShell cmdlets working with Azure Service Buses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.servicebus/v0.0.2/azurerm.servicebus). Here is [the intro to installing the AzureRM module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azureps-cmdlets-docs/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662795/deleting-dead-topics-in-azure-service-bus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, it is not support to delete topic directly just with given connection string in Powershell cmd currently. But we could do that by [including a reference the .NET assembly for Service Bus](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content-nlnl/blob/master/articles/service-bus/service-bus-powershell-how-to-provision.md). 
The following is demo code:

```
$path = "C:\xx\Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll" # The path of the Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll
$topicName = "topic1"
$connectionString = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
Import-Module $path
Write-Output "The [Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll] assembly has been successfully added to the script."
$NamespaceManager= [Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager]::CreateFromConnectionString($connectionString);
Write-Output "NamespaceManager has been successfully created."
$NamespaceManager.DeleteTopic($topicName)
Write-Output "$topicName has been successfully deleted."
```

[image]

If we could Login-AzureRmAccount, we could use [Remove-AzureRmServiceBusTopic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.servicebus/v0.0.2/remove-azurermservicebustopic) to do that.